ERROR: failed to install packages to new root
Я впервые устанавливаю arch Linux и при попытке развернуть базовую систему появляется ошибка

Где расположен корень системы, какая файловая система?

Три раздела: efi, root и home. Файловая система расположенна на диске /dev/sda. На диске таблица GPT

Три раздела: efi, root и home. Файловая система расположенна на диске /dev/sda. На диске таблица GPT -- вместо перечисления нужно просто показать, например,вывод команды lsblk -f или лучше даже lsblk -o NAME,PTTYPE,FSTYPE,FSAVAIL,FSUSE%,MOUNTPOINTS,LABEL. Но похоже вы банально забыли примонтировать нужные разделы в папку /mnt

Installation_guide#Mount_the_file_systems

12.4 GiB/s? Ты на МКС живёшь? )

Ты же не забыл примонтировать раздел? Твой коментарий подсказывает, что ты мог немного запутаться, и попытаться примонтировать диск /dev/sda вместо раздела /dev/sdaN.
/dev/sda -- это всё устройство, то есть весь жёсткий диск. Таблица GPT дробит жёсткий диск на разделы, которым Linux даёт имя от всего устройства: /dev/sda1, /dev/sda5 и т.д. от жёсткого диска /dev/sda.
Кстати, опять же: файловые системы пишутся также в разделы, а не на диск в общем.

Кстати, опять же: файловые системы пишутся также в разделы, а не на диск в общем. -- справедливости ради нужно заметить что файловую систему можно напрямую закатать на диск, таблицу разделов придумали когда нужно иметь на диске больше одного раздела.

тоже думал упомянуть об этом, но умолчал, т.к. в реалиях ПК это сложно реализуемо: гораздо легче держать обособленным загрузочный раздел (как минимум только его), т.к. efi работает только файловой системой FATN, которая не особо-то годится для остальной части большого диска.  Разве что это может быть полезно системе с несколькими дисками

в данном случае, кстати, уверен, что запись одного целого диска -- отстут от инструкции, который этой инструкцией был превращён в снежный ком
